# Can the Data wires of a USB cable power a LED?

Tags: usb

I got a USB wire from an old mouse and the wires were soldered to the circuit as: Green - D, Orange - C, Blue - V and White - G. 
Assuming orange was red and white was black; they should be VCC and GND respectively. Meaning they transmit power.
[image]

However I found that the green and blue writes could power a LED, with blue being positive and green negative. The other two couldn't.
I don't have a voltmeter to check so I was wondering whether the wires were mixed up or if this is normal. If the wires are mixed up, how do I separate D+ from D-?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a multimeter and ring them from the pins.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Umm. Could you elaborate on that? (Sorry)

Comment: Set your meter on the "beep" thing (continuity testing. If you don't have it, just use the ohmmeter to check for low resistance), then open a pinout diagram of a USB connector and check the continuity between the pins and the wires, such that you establish the true correspondence.

Comment: Data, Clock, Voltage, Ground. Sounds like a throwback to PS/2 mice.

Comment: If you are going to power a LED from USB, remember to put an appropriate resistor in series with the LED to limit current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the pinout (from the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Pinouts) page)

[image]

Simply check continuity with your multimeter, as Eugene Sh says, and **ignore whatever wire color code they happen to have used**.